# Erro ao adicionar view no visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Olá, estou iniciando em asp.net mvc e estou tendo esse problema ao adicionar uma view, alguém saberia do que se trata esse erro?

Erro:

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>       Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Controller:

```
using AplicacaoLivro.Contexts;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AplicacaoLivro.Controllers
{
    public class FabricantesController : Controller
    {
        private EFContext context = new EFContext();

        // GET: Fabricantes
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(context.Fabricantes.OrderBy(c => c.Nome));
        }
    }
}
```

Context:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using AplicacaoLivro.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace AplicacaoLivro.Contexts
{
    public class EFContext : DbContext
    {
        public EFContext() : base("ASP_NET_MVC_CS") { }
        public IDbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<Fabricante> Fabricantes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Para obter mais informações sobre como configurar seu aplicativo ASP.NET, visite
   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ASP_NET_MVC_CS"  connectionString="server=localhost;port=5432;user id=postgres;password=22385129d@;database=Desenvolvimento"    providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
           invariant="Npgsql"
           support="FF"
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql"
           type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.6.0" newVersion="3.2.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <!--<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>-->
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

Clicar com o botão direito do mouse em cima do seu projeto que está sendo mostrado do lado direito, no solution explore, e clicar na opção -> "Set as startup project".